# Worksheet Selection Change Events

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I am attempting to program to open a text input box whenever a cell within a certain range is selected.  I am relatively new to VBA, and especially new to event handling, and was wondering if anyone had any advise on how I could get this code to function? As it stands now, I am not getting any error messages when I compile the project, but the code does not appear to be working as I had hoped. Current code:

```
Sub InputUser()
  Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox("Please enter your User ID.")
    If strName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "User:" & strName
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sheet19.Range("L3:L300")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.Run ("InputUser")
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

-- Thank you for your time!

Comment: I checked this code and its work fine.
Do you want check Sheet19 Worksheet or other?

Comment: Yes, Sheet19 is where I want to be able to select a cell within Range("L3:L300") and have the inputbox appear upon the cell selection.  I have re-checked multiple times and cannot get the macro to call by selection of the cell range. It does appear when I run it manually, but because the sheet will be for users that do not know how to run macros, I wanted it to be as easy and self-sufficient as possible... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get an error at

```
Application.Run ("InputUser") saying
```

[image]

which if changed to `Call InputUser` works fine.

Help on the Run method isn't enlightening. AFAIK `Call` and `Application.Run` should be interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I made the change from Application.Run to "Call InputUser" and the cell selection is still not prompting the inputbox macro to run.